# Control are not loaded in designer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, designer

A very simple example. I have two classes:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl  {  }

public partial class MyControl : BaseControl 
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

I can open BaseControl in designer mode, but MyControl can not (VS 2008). I **CAN NOT** just inherit class MyControl from class UserControl. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I found the solution. VS designer requires InitializeComponent method in base class (in my case in BaseControl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have classes defined this way:

```
public class BaseControl : UserControl  
{  
    public BaseControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}

public partial class MyControl : BaseControl 
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `InitializeComponent()` method is generated by the designer and actually creates the controls, sets the properties and adds them to the controls collection on your UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decorate your class MyControl with the `[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]` attribute

and write `MyControlDesigner` class that inherited `IDesigner`